# "Samsung keyboard keeps stopping" error message. After reboot no keyboard is accessible and I cannot unlock the device

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-note, swype

The device is a Samsung Note 5 recently updated from Sprint running the Swype keyboard.

The error message "Samsung keyboard keeps stopping" is appearing over and over after trying to send an emoji in a text message. The keyboard area is a black space.

I rebooted the device to attempt to clear the error.

After reboot it requires a typed password.

The following issues occur:

- No keyboard appears when touching the password textbox.
- No keyboard appears when touching the keyboard settings menu button.
- The Power button does not power cycle the device.
- The Reset button does work.
- If you open the camera via the quick launch from the lock screen the "Samsung keyboard keeps stopping" message appears for each time you attempt a keyboard UI action.

The device appears bricked. Other advice online suggests factory reset. Is there a way to revert the device to a working keyboard without a factory reset?

Answer (score 2):

Enable Emergency Mode. This shuts down to only essential services.

This reverts the device to the default Samsung keyboard and will allow you to enter the password.

You can then disabled Emergency Mode go into the settings and re-enabled Swype.

Source:

https://androidforums.com/threads/samsung-keyboard-keeps-stopping-locked-out-of-phone.1166997/#post-7579781